# How to remove dropdown icon from text parameter in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I Am trying to remove the dropdown icon from the text parameter in SSRS.

Step follow:-

1. In the "Available Values" section and selected the "None" option.
2. In the "Default Values" tab and selected the "None" option.

but still, the dropdown icon is coming on the UI, can someone help me with this,

below is the screenshot

UI Screenshot

[image]

Report parameter Screenshot

1. General section

[image]

2. Available Values

[image]

3. Default Values

[image]

4. Advanced

[image]

Comment: I can't see why the dropdown should be there, it shoudl only show if the "Allow multiple Values" option is selected (which I can see it isn't). So this looks like a bug. Does this happen in Visual Studio/Report Builder? if so what version? I would try to remove the parameter, clean the solutions, close and reopen VS/RB and add the parameter again. Personally, I've never seen this behaviour before.

Comment: the dropdown icon is not coming in the report builder but when I try to check with the asp.net web page(browser )this icon is coming

Comment: I would remove the report from the server and redeploy it. I know that some parameter properties (such as default values) do not get overwritten when you deploy updates to reports so they have to be done directly on the server version or what I normally do is drop the report from the server and redeploy it (I'm using Visual Studio).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the report from your server and redeploying it. I've had many cases where deploying doesn't actually change the parameter settings, even if you delete the parameter entirely. Deleting and redeploying the report is usually the solution for me.